# Unable to deploy flask app on heroku having nltk

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

When I deploy this to github, I get this error

```
ERROR: google-auth 1.14.1 has requirement setuptools>=40.3.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.0.1 which is incompatible.
       Installing collected packages: cachetools, certifi, chardet, click, Corpora, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Flask, pytz, urllib3, idna, requests, pyasn1, rsa, six, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, protobuf, googleapis-common-protos, google-api-core, httplib2, google-auth-httplib2, uritemplate, google-api-python-client, gunicorn, joblib, regex, tqdm, nltk, numpy, python-dateutil, pandas, retrying, plotly, pycountry, vader-sentiment, youtube-data-api, youtube-python
       Successfully installed Corpora-1.0 Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 cachetools-4.1.0 certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 google-api-core-1.17.0 google-api-python-client-1.8.2 google-auth-1.14.1 google-auth-httplib2-0.0.3 googleapis-common-protos-1.51.0 gunicorn-20.0.4 httplib2-0.17.3 idna-2.9 itsdangerous-1.1.0 joblib-0.14.1 nltk-3.5 numpy-1.18.4 pandas-1.0.3 plotly-4.6.0 protobuf-3.11.3 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pycountry-19.8.18 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 regex-2020.4.4 requests-2.23.0 retrying-1.3.3 rsa-4.0 six-1.14.0 tqdm-4.46.0 uritemplate-3.0.1 urllib3-1.25.9 vader-sentiment-3.2.1.1 youtube-data-api-0.0.17 youtube-python-1.0.13
-----> Downloading NLTK corpora…
-----> Downloading NLTK packages: corpora wordnet pros_cons reuters vader_lexicon setiment-vader
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
[nltk_data] Error loading corpora: Package 'corpora' not found in
[nltk_data]     index
Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 2538, in <module>
    halt_on_error=options.halt_on_error,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 790, in download
    choice = input().strip()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here is my repo
https://github.com/ejekanshjain/youtube-comment-sentiment

But this runs perfectly fine on my local machine

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Corpora is not a package within NLTK. If you try downloading it, you will get an error. Remove Corpora from your nltk.txt file.

Comment: Still getting error after removing Corpora from nltk.txt

Comment: You put the wrong package in your nltk.txt. Insteas of sentiment-vader, it has to be vader_lexicon

Comment: please edit your original post with the new error message it is showing. It is likely not the same error message.